# Always load entity for ApplicationUser (.NET MVC, Identity)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-core

I am having problems loading a entity that I have assigned to the ApplicationUser in my .NET core MVC application.

I have added one of my entities to the user class, see code below:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public int? AzureBlobResourceId { get; set; }

   [ForeignKey("AzureBlobResourceId")]
   public AzureBlobResource AzureBlobResource { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally I want the AzureBlobResource object to be loaded when retrieving the user from the UserManager

```
private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync()
{
   return _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
}
```

Unfortunately though the AzureBlobResource object always is null, even when the AzureBlobResourceId has a value.

What am I missing here?

Thanks, Nikolai

Comment: Can you show us the declaration for the _userManager?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your userstore

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {
   public int? AzureBlobResourceId { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("AzureBlobResourceId")]
   public AzureBlobResource AzureBlobResource { get; set; } 
}

 public class MyAppUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyAppUserStore(DbContext context, IdentityErrorDescriber describer = null) : base(context, describer)
    {
    }
    public override async Task<ApplicationUser> FindByIdAsync(string userId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        return await Context.Set<ApplicationUser>().Include(p => p.AzureBlobResource).FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.Id == userId, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

And in Sturtup.cs add

```
ervices.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()

                .AddUserStore<MyAppUserStore >()
                .AddUserManager<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```